# Get Mercurial next commit hash

Tags: mercurial

I am at revision 56, hash 6af16aa3edf8. Next revision will be 57, with hash ???. Is there a way to know the hash of revision 57? I need it in a pre-commit hook.

WHY THO?

I developed a script, called via pre-commit hook, that update some version files. That way, the compiled executables can give all info about the revision they are build from. I'm adding the revision number of the current commit in my version file, simply retrieved with "parent revision number + 1". Since the revision number is not reliable when collaborating with other people on the same repository, I prefer to add the hash, too. Don't know how to retrieve it...

Comment: Hash is even less reliable, because it is **generated** based on file changes.

Comment: @arrowd With "reliable" I mean that it identifies a revision univocally, while rev number doesn't. Hash (changeset ID) is based on file changes AND position in change history. The complete 40 digits will be exclusive for a given revision. https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ChangeSetID

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot predict the next hash even when you know its changeset completely. The commit *time* also plays a role there:

```
~/hg-test $ hg ci -m "b in foo"
~/hg-test $ hg id
d65d61e6898a tip
~/hg-test $ hg rollback
~/hg-test $ hg ci -m "b in foo"
~/hg-test $ hg id
c7f5ff744e43 tip
```

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Nodeid

I suggest to solve your problem such:
In your build tools, query whether the project is built from a repository. If so: retrieve the repository information. E.g.

```
ver = $(hg log -r. -T"{node|short} from {date|isodate}")
```

will give you

```
c7f5ff744e43 from 2017-07-26 14:05 +0200
```

Generate the version file from that information in your build chain on the fly

For distribution purposes, generate and amend this file to the package, so that the build process, when it finds it is not started from a repository checkout, still has a version file it can make use of.

Comment: Thanks for the info and the hints. I thought about something similar, like a pre-build step that update version info based on the current rev. Better if I could have had all the info ready when jumping from one commit to another, but well...

Comment: I consider that part of the build step :)
If you use any continuous integration, then you anyway have the revision information from the repo itself - and generating the version information file is part of the build.

 If you pack your code for distribution, then it's part of the packet creation to generate a small file with version information.

Comment: specify the date :) hg commit -m 'msg' -d "2017-01-01 01:01:01" :)

Comment: @Tom yea, that actually does work. But usually that's more hassle than one wants to go for :)

Comment: Remembered why I don't like a pre-build step that edit a source. After a build, the repository is in a modified state, so not "clean", although not actual "meaningful" edit was done.

Comment: @Tom That looks like a hell of an hack! If I got it right, by specifying the date I can predict the HASH code. Is that what you are saying? Anyway, specifying a wrong date (e.g., always the same date) will generate a quite confusing repository. One can pick the current system date, that will differ by some seconds with the actual commit date/time. Also, where can I find the actual algorithm used to compute the hash code?

Comment: as by my answer you are not supposed to track the source file which feeds the version into the code... thus the repo will not be modified.
As described in the link: it's using the sha1 hash algorithm. And what exactly is hashed... is found in mercurial's source

Comment: @planetmaker I missed your hint about not including version file in the repository. About the Nodeid wiki link, it'is quite concise, at least... I've checked the mercurial source files, but since I'm a Python newbie it's quite hard for me to figure out the flow. Well, I'll think a little more about the best (for me) approach